# How to take advantage of polymporphism without modifying the base classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I am grading student's Java programming assignments using Junit tests in Eclipse. My goal is to modify the student's submissions as little as possible, but my current approach forces me type **"extends ParentClass"** in their submissions.

My current approach is to put each student assignment in its own package and extend the classes I want to test from a parentclass

STUDENT A APPLE EXAMPLE CLASS

```
package PA04.studentA;

import PA04.providedCode.TestApple;

public class apple extends TestApple {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Look I can Print A");
    }
}
```

STUDENT B APPLE EXAMPLE CLASS

```
package PA04.studentB;

import PA04.providedCode.TestApple;

public class apple extends TestApple {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Look I can Print B");
    }
}
```

TESTAPPLE PARENT CLASS

```
package PA04.providedCode;

public abstract class TestApple {
    public abstract void print();
}
```

Then, I use a helper method of the superclass parameter type to verify the behavior of the students programs

STUDENT TEST PROGRAM

```
@Test
void testStudentA() {
     PA04.studentA.apple a = new PA04.studentA.apple();
     packageTest(a);
}
@Test
void testStudentB() {
     PA04.studentB.apple b = new PA04.studentB.apple();
     packageTest(b);
}

/**
 * helper method to test behavior of classes with the same name
* but different packages
*/
private void packageTest(TestApple a) {
  a.print();        
}
```

OUTPUT OF STUDENT TEST PROGRAM

```
Look I can Print A
Look I can Print B
```

The output is what I expect, but this approach **requires me to modify the student's programs to extend the parent class**

Is there a way to be able to use a helper method for different student classes without modifying them?

Comment: Did you consider using a JUnit tests to validate non-private members ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a one time test and you don't need to maintain it further, you can get away with `reflection`. You can change your `packageTest()` method to:

```
private void packageTest(Object a) {
try {
    Method method = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("print");
    method.invoke(a);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For future assignments, I strongly recommend that you provide `Interface` to your students which they must implement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't think of an easy solution to your problem. It's probably worth looking into using a macro to add `extends ParentClass` to each package. [Here's](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) a tutorial for making a macro in IntelliJ.